# How does this program to count vowels work?

Tags: pascal

I want to understand this code, especially `PROCEDURE`

```
PROGRAM vowels; 

USES crt; 

{Program that counts the number of vowels in a sentence} 

CONST space=' '; 
      maxchar=80; 

TYPE vowel=(a,e,i,o,u); 

VAR buffer:ARRAY[1..maxchar] of char; 
    vowelcount:ARRAY[vowel] of integer; 

PROCEDURE initialize; 

VAR ch:vowel; 

BEGIN 
     FOR ch:=a TO u DO 
     BEGIN 
          vowelcount[ch]:=0; 
     END; 
END; 

PROCEDURE textinput; 

VAR index:integer; 

BEGIN 
     writeln('Input a sentence'); 
     FOR index:=1 TO maxchar DO 
         IF eoln THEN buffer[index]:=space 
         ELSE read(buffer[index]); 
         readln; 
END; 

PROCEDURE analysis; 

VAR index:integer; 
    ch:vowel; 

BEGIN 
     index:=1; 
     WHILE index<>maxchar+1 DO 
     BEGIN 
          IF buffer[index] IN ['a','e','i','o','u'] THEN 
          BEGIN 
               CASE buffer[index] OF 
               'a':ch:=a; 
               'e':ch:=e; 
               'i':ch:=i; 
               'o':ch:=o; 
               'u':ch:=u; 
               END; 
               vowelcount[ch]:=vowelcount[ch]+1; 
          END; 
          index:=index+1; 
     END; 
END; 

PROCEDURE vowelout; 

VAR ch:vowel; 

BEGIN 
     clrscr; 
     writeln; 
     writeln('   a   e   i   o   u'); 
     FOR ch:=a TO u DO 
     write(vowelcount[ch]:4); 
     writeln; 
END; 

BEGIN 
     initialize; 
     textinput; 
     analysis; 
     vowelout; 
END;
```

Comment: It counts the number of vowels in a scentence

Answer (score 10):

Overall: Okay this code is counting the number of vowels supplied in the input string.

Lets Begin....

> TYPE vowel=(a,e,i,o,u); VAR
>   buffer:ARRAY[1..maxchar] of char;
>   vowelcount:ARRAY[vowel] of integer;

This code is defining a list of the vowels in english (a,e,i,o,u).

> PROCEDURE initialize; VAR ch:vowel;
>   BEGIN FOR ch:=a TO u DO BEGIN
>   vowelcount[ch]:=0; END; END;

It then defines a variable to collect the number of each vowel, called vowelcount. That variable is an array, looks sort of like this:

```
vowelcount[a]=0;
vowelcount[e]=0;
vowelcount[i]=0; #... etc
```

Then the procedure "Analysis" is defined. This takes the input from the screen (which will be called later on in the program) and steps through each letter in the input.

> WHILE index<>maxchar+1 DO BEGIN IF
>   buffer[index] IN ['a','e','i','o','u']
>   THEN BEGIN CASE buffer[index] OF
>   'a':ch:=a; 'e':ch:=e; 'i':ch:=i;
>   'o':ch:=o; 'u':ch:=u; END;

If any of those letters happens to be in the list of letters than matches a vowel, then it will add one to the number in the vowelcount array above. (vowelcount[ch]:=vowelcount[ch]+1) where ch is the matched letter. As you can see this is only triggered if it is a valid vowel (IF buffer[index] IN ['a','e','i','o','u'] )

Finally. The main code of the program, or what is actually run:

> BEGIN clrscr; writeln; writeln(' a e i
>   o u'); FOR ch:=a TO u DO
>   write(vowelcount[ch]:4); writeln; END;
>
> BEGIN initialize; textinput; analysis;
>   vowelout; END.

This basically strings the application together, starting by clearing the screen (in a dos prompt) and then outputting the vowels onto the screen. It then adds some formatting and outputs the current count of vowelcount (as above). 
It will then request your input and finally it will output the contents of vowelcount again, which has been updated with the vowelcounts from the input you made.

Comment: @Orbling : Lol, nah not really i think i got carried away. Happy new year. @Manal good luck with your exam, i seriously hope you can understand it before you do it but it is quite simple :)